# How to allow .slideDown and .slideUp to finish animation when using .stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I've put together a very simple hover effect using jQuery. The jsFiddle (below) only shows one image but this would ideally work on a grid of images.

*I've managed to get most of this working, it just needs a slight tweak.*

When the cursor hovers over the image a `.description` div slides up, it slides down when the cursor leaves the hover area (the image).

I'm using `.stop(true,false)` to avoid animation build up, and to allow the animation to finish.

I'm also using `.delay(800);` this makes `.slideDown(600)` wait before sliding down.

**I'd like to be able to fade the `.description` div in and out as it slides up and down.**

I can't figure out how I'd do this... Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".description").addClass("hide");

    $('.item').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).find('.description').stop(true,false).slideDown(600).delay(800);
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find('.description').slideUp(600);
     }
   );  
});
```

[See jsFiddle below for HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/jcvzx9hr/20/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/jcvzx9hr/23/)

```
.animate(
    {
        opacity: 0
    }, 
    {
        queue: false,
        duration: 600
    });
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Looks good! I don't suppose you know how to make this mobile friendly? Just checked my original code on a iPhone and the hover gets converted into a touch (which is good) but it gets stuck?

Comment: @StephenMeehan for mobile you should really ask a different question as the implementation is a lot different. You would have to bind touchstart/touchend... it's a lot to explain, better off a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this, fades as it goes up and down. I separated the actual content from the description so fade can be done on it while the slide is on the description

http://jsfiddle.net/jcvzx9hr/24/

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/239x179" alt="Demo">
    <div class="description">
        <div class="content">
            <p> <strong>Project Name Here</strong>

            </p>
            <p class="intro"> <em>Duis ornare interdum ornare integer id vulputate sapien suspendisse quis mauris enim proin eleifend pharetra orci, quis feugiat massa molestie non.</em>

            </p> <a class="btn" href="#">View case study</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".description").addClass('hide');
    $('.content').fadeOut(0);

    $('.item').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).find('.description').stop(true, false).slideDown(600);
        $(this).find('.content').fadeIn(600);
      },

      function () {
        $(this).find('.description').slideUp(600);
        $(this).find('.content').fadeOut(600);
      }
    );
});
```

Update - to fade the blue background, simply move the background to the content div

http://jsfiddle.net/jcvzx9hr/27/

```
.item {
    margin: 0 5px 0px 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 239px;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #179CFE;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Great, Ideally the blue background would also fade in - not just the text. Stackoverflow is brilliant!